# How to find Temp dir using reg key

Tags: windows, command-line, registry

I am trying to run a script on startup from a temp dir. In the HCKU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, I've made a record

> "%temp%\script.bat"

But that seems not work. Is there a way find temp dir by means of reg key?

Comment: `reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` should output `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type for your registry entry. Could fail if it gives the `REG_SZ` type.

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work

Comment: What  doesn't work? Where is the `script.bat` saved? In your question, what the **temp dir** description stands for?   Is it the same _temp dir_ as shown in `echo %temp%` from user's command prompt? Or `echo %temp%` from elevated (run as administrator) command prompt?